# Retrofit2 - Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter - Proguard

Tags: android, retrofit2, proguard, minify

I'm doing ProGuard in my app as:

```
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

and when I try to do an http call with Retrofit2 I get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.

The `Service` is:

```
interface ContentService {

    @GET
    fun getCMSCon(@Url url: String): Single<CMSCon>

}
```

**It doesn't happen when `minifyEnabled false` and `shrinkResources false`**

I took a research on Internet and I ended up modifying the `proguard-rules.pro` as:

```
# Retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
```

but nothing changed.

The `@Url` is passed from `res` and literal, to check that there's not a problem with the Flavors.

Comment: did you tried adding the interface which has those method calls post or get. I think you can try adding them there too in rules. because it might be shrinking them too.

Comment: That is true @vikaskumar, it works that way. Isn't there any other way to do it?

Comment: try this #-keep class com.your.package.webinterface.;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution would be applying `@Keep` in any call described in any `interface` as Service:

```
@Keep
@GET
fun getCMSConfig(@Url url: String): Single<CMSConfig>
```